# What is XEED and where can I get more information about it?

Tags: java, xceed

The company where I work recently got a new client who owns a software written in "Java XEED." What is XEED? Where can I get information about it? My company needs to make a decision about whether to maintain the software or convert it to another programming language.

I'd appreciate information about XEED as well as links to, for example, official project sites.

Comment: So, do you mean XEED or Xceed? Xceed is a software company that makes .NET components, so that's unlikely. Googling for Java XEED doesn't yield any meaningful results. Have you asked your colleagues? Or the client?

Comment: Any chance that it's just some proprietary scripting language?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean [xceed](http://xceed.com/CS/tags/Java/default.aspx)